# How to access Oracle database present on the host machine from VMPlayer?

Tags: java, oracle, oracle11g, virtual-machine, oracle-sqldeveloper

I am using windows8 64 bit , that is my host.
I have set vmplayer 64bit ubuntu .
I have Oracle 11g database and SQL developer on my host machine.
however I wish to test my app (that uses the database present on host machine) from the ubuntu present on my vmware. 
so how do I access database from vmware ?? also is it possible to access sqldeveloper (present on host machine) as well from vmware ?

I hope my question is clear

thanks

Comment: If the Host is visible via its ip address, then use the ip address.

Comment: no .. its on localhost on the host machine. It doesn't have an IP addr

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to set the network adapter on Ubuntu VM into Bridged mode in vmplayer settings, then the VM acts as if it was another computer sitting on your network.

So if you have firewall open on 1521 on your host (default port for Oracle DB) you should be able to connect from Ubuntu VM onto Windows8 host running Oracle using SQLDeveloper.

Also your app if it connects directly onto DB using e.g. JDBC should be able to connect from VM.